# Storing images in int[] matrix?

Tags: android, matrix, swipe

This is a code I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer). It is storing the images in an array and is displayed accordingly when I run it. I want to store the images in a **matrix** and do that. i.e. **swipe** up,down,right,left for different images. I also want to skip some positions in the matrix. some sort of picture-map kind of thing. Is it possible editing **this** code? Or will I have to use a completely new syntax? How do I do it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.chiang_mai,
        R.drawable.himeji,
        R.drawable.petronas_twin_tower,
        R.drawable.ulm
};

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return mImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  Context context = MainActivity.this;
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
  int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
      R.dimen.padding_medium);
  imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
  ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
  return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use Picasso who does image caching on your behalf. Makes such things pretty easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depends on the number of pictures you have.

- If there are not so many, you could give `TableLayout` a try. However, this implies starting over. You will have to implement scrolling, for instance, yourself.
- If there are many pictures, you will have to work with (one or two) adapter classes. I believe there are two basic options.

  - You could reuse the code you have, make as many `ImagePagerAdapter` s as you want to have rows, put those adapters into an array which could be the data for a `VerticalViewPager` (https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager, for instance). This is probably the most difficult solution, but you will also learn a lot.
  - You could implement a `GridView` which is scrollable in two dimensions and needs an adapter, a `BaseAdapter` for example, which is different from the adapter you have in your code. However, if you can manage the skipping of positions (which you write about and which I don't really understand) in a one-dimensional array, too, this is a viable solution.